# Existence of geodesic convex functions

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry

By a result of  Shing-Tung Yau [[1974, Mathematische Annalen 207: 269-270](https://eudml.org/doc/162545)], there are no non-trivial continuous geodesic convex functions on complete manifolds with finite volume.
What happened if we relaxed assumptions, for example:

> **Q1** if we consider weaker condition than continuity, for example, considering "lower semi-continuity"?
>
> **Q2** if we consider a generalized notion of convexity, for example, quasi-convexity?

Any result or reference is appreciated.

Comment: I found recently [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324389818_On_the_spherical_quasi-convexity_of_quadratic_functions) related paper (and [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316475480_On_the_spherical_convexity_of_quadratic_functions)) about quasiconvex functions on a geodesic convex subset of a sphere.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this statement was proved by Richard Bishop and Barrett O’Neill [see Proposition 2.2 in “Manifolds of negative curvature.” Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 145 (1969)].

For **Q1**, the asnwer is "yes".
Let $d$ be the dimension of the manifold.
Assume $f$ is not constant.

It is easy to get a converging sequence of points, say $p_n\to p_\infty$, such that $f(p_n)\to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$.
Choose $d$ points $a_1,\dots, a_d$ near $p_\infty$ in nearly ortogonal directions from $p_\infty$.

Consider polygonal geodesic lines starting from $p_n$ and going in the directions opposite to $a_1,\dots, a_d$.
The ends of these lines fill a cube $\square_n$ with one vertex at $p_n$.
By convexity of $f$, the values in $\square_n$ are large if $n$ is large.
Note that the intersection $\square$ of all $\square_n$ have nonempty interior.
It follows that $f|_\square\equiv\infty$; by convexity, $f\equiv \infty$ --- a contradiction.

For **Q2**, the asnwer is also "yes". Moreover, it requires only minor modification of the solution of "Volume and convexity" in my [PIGTIKAL](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0290).

Instead of condition on gradinet, you can get an open set $\Omega$ such that $\phi^{t}(\Omega)\cap \Omega=\varnothing$ for any $t\ge T$.
Observe that $\phi^{m\cdot T}(\Omega)\cap \phi^{n\cdot T}(\Omega)=\varnothing$ for any positive integers $m\ne n$.
Then you arrive at a contradition the same way.

For **Q1+Q2** the answer is "no"; that is, there is a lower-semcontinuous quasiconvex function $f$ that is not constant:
Choose a rotationally symmetric manifolds of finite volume.
Let $z$ be the center of rotation.
Note that there is no geodesic loop with base at $z$.
So we may assume that $f(z)=0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\ne z$.